# PyQt QtDesigner lost of the windows minimize buttons

Tags: windows, qt, pyqt

My problem is only in Qtdesigner.
I am using QtDesigner v4.8.4 to define my HMI for a pyqt project. In this editor the window I have drown, has got a reduce and a close button in right up corner. I am sorry I wanted to show it to you with screenshots but I don't have enough reputation.

When I use it or previsualize it (with Ctrl + R), I lose the "minimize button" of the window and its functionnality.
Do you have the same behavior?

I have a useless ? button instead and the close button. How could I keep it to minimize my window ?

Thanks a lot for any advice!

Comment: Please give more detail, such as, class your implemented, pyqt version, etc... Thanks

Comment: I got it, I have same with you, but not worry about it. When your implement in pyqt, by default It's have all button (min, max and close Button). Or your can set specified button your want to show.

Comment: Hmm Ok so it is corrected by the pyQt code ? Can you please show an example of implementation of the minimize button of the up right corner because for my script, when I run it I have the same behavior as when you previsualize it with Ctrl R, the reduce button has gone ! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I use it or previsualize it (with Ctrl + R), I lose the "minimize button" of the window and its functionnality.

**Answer** : This is not bug, I just preview your widget only. If your implement in pyqt can see all button for windows.

[image]

**Picture: Show previsualize of Qt4 Designer doesn't have "minimize button"**

[image]

**Picture: Show running of PyQt4 (It default have "minimize button")"**

> Can you please show an example of implementation of the minimize button of the up right corner because for my script

OK, Keyword is implement event in widget by this method `QWidget.changeEvent (self, QEvent)`
, Please see my example code, Hope is helps;

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

(loadUserInterface, loadQWidget) = uic.loadUiType('QWelcomeWidget.ui')

class QWelcomeWidget (loadQWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        loadQWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = loadUserInterface()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    def changeEvent (self, eventQEvent):
        if eventQEvent.type() == QtCore.QEvent.WindowStateChange:
            if self.windowState() & QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimized:
                print 'Window Minimized'
        QtGui.QWidget.changeEvent(self, eventQEvent)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    appQApplication = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainQWidget = QWelcomeWidget()
    mainQWidget.show()
    # Start Application
    sys.exit(appQApplication.exec_())
```

---

**References** : http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#changeEvent

---

Regards,

Comment: Thank you for this long and very complete explanation. It answers to my question, in fact I was using a Dialog instead of a Form. Thousands of thanks. Have a good day Kistsune!

Answer (score 0):

convert your .ui file to (.py)python file using

```
pyuic4 filename.ui 

sudo pyuic4 -x ptqt_filename.ui -o python_file_name.py
```

Now run that python file,you will be able to see all controls

```
python pyqt_first_ui.py
```